# Database access and battery friendly apps

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'd like to save statistics about the usage of the ad networks in my app. Basically I want to maintain the count of the number of times an ad network is requested, makes an impression, or fails in the request each day.

My initial idea is have an SQLite database with the following columns

```
[ day , networkId, requests, impressions, fails]
```

But I'm considering the following performance/battery drain possible issue:

Since I use 3 ad network (1 main and 2 as backfill) the worst case is:

- Network A requested
- Network A fails
- Network B requested
- Network B fails
- Network C requested
- Network C success.

All within ~4 seconds. If each one of this points make an access to the database for updating the corresponding row, the overhead is significantly? Should I implement some kind of cache in memory and bulk insert the values (seizing also the pair of [request+success] or [request+fail] making a single update?) or can I use directly the database

Comment: You want to store SQLite database on user's phone? But how you are going to extract it from his phone?

Comment: Sending it in the future to a web service

Comment: That makes sense. I would suggest you create `ArrayList` of [`ContentProviderOperation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html) until you ad network request succeeded and then use [`ContentResolver.applyBatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of the object model technigue...by this whenever u get a change in data you can write to the objects...and at a certain time interval you can wrtite the data in the object model to the sql database...

the only problem I see is if ur activity is killed...or stop the object model will get empty...you may avoid this by writing the data to database when there is a chance of ur activity getting finished or killed.